# VBA vs VSTO for excel to powerpoint

Tags: vba, vsto, excel-2007, powerpoint

I'm currently considering a number of options for copying an excel sheet into a powerpoint presentation.

1. Using VBA select a excel sheet, copy the range and place it into a newly created powerpoint slide as an image.
2. I create excel automated html of a sheet, once that html is saved(initially), i create an image off of the html.
3. Using VSTO, i open Excel copy each object and paste it into a new powerpoint slide, using the clipboard(or another copy method).

These operations will be called frequently, by many different users - all the actual operation occurs on a single server.

What would the pros and cons of each approach be? Are there any prefered or better optimized techniques available?

Comment: **A)** i'm not sure that i understand how #2 relates to the question of VBA vs. VSTO. **B)** how exactly are #1 and #3 different? **C)** in #1 and #3, are they pasted into a new slide in an existing deck or a new deck all together as slide 1? **D)** can you describe a little more about what actions the end-users will take, where they will take them from and how they take them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Pro:

- Speed

Contra:

- The inserted Data can't be copied, altered, viewed within excel etc.

**Option 3:**

A couple of years ago I wrote a similar **VBA**-Procedure that created a >1000 Slides Presentation from an Excel Sheet. The method was called from Excel and went AFAIR like this(pseudo-code):

```
newSlide = PowerPoint.AddSlide
embeddedSheet = newSlide.Add OLEObject(Excel-Sheet)
embeddedSheet.Range(..., ...) = srcSheet.Range(..., ...)
someFormating(embeddedSheet)
createPieChart(embeddedSheet.Range(..,...))
resize(embeddedSheet)
embeddedSheet.Save
embeddedSheet.Close
```

Pro / Contra based on my experience with the method above.

Pro:

- The Sheet is embedded in PowerPoint

  - you can alter the Data and run Macros on it.
  - you do not need to keep the original Excel sheet.

Contra:

- The Output-File is bigger
- The Process uses a lot of RAM.
- The Process takes relatively long. AFAIR 1k Slides took about 10 Minutes on the computer in my office. Creating the OleObject took the majority of the time.